# SAS HOW TO DO CALCULATION FOR A GROUP WITH MULTIPLE ROWS

Tags: loops, sas

I have a dataset with student ID, score, and assignment number. For each student, they have five assignments, I need to calculate a final score for them. If the student has more than one missing score, then the final score is a missing value. Else, the final score is 0.7*(average of the first 4 assignment scores)+0.3(last assignment scores).

How can i do it in SAS?

[image]

Comment: Please post example data as text, not photograph.  Show the expected result for the example data.  How do you define "first 4" assignments?  Does that mean assignment numbers 1 to 4?  What code did you try?  Did it run? If not what errors did you get? If it ran explain how the results were wrong.

Answer (score 1):

1. Transpose to a wide format to make this easier for you
2. What do you want to do if you have 1 missing? That's what you've shown but your criteria says "more than one missing score" so it's not clear how you want to deal with the situation of exactly one missing. I've left that to you.

```
data have;
infile cards dlm='09'x truncover;
input Student_ID    Score   Assignment;
cards;
1   64  1
1   74  2
1   71  3
1   72  4
1   67  5
2   88  1
2   66  2
2   64  3
2   76  4
2   .   5
3   66  1
3   66  2
3   85  3
3   63  4
3   62  5
;;;;

proc transpose data=have out=wide prefix=hw_;
by student_id;
id assignment;
var score;
run;

data want;
set wide;

weighted_score = sum(0.7*mean(of hw_1-hw_4) , 0.3*hw_5);
n_miss = cmiss(of hw_1-hw_5);

if n_miss >= 1 then weighted_score = 0;

run;
```